# LDAP:// OpenDirectory to ActiveDirectory query changes

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

this works to connect to the OpenDirectory LDAP

```
<add name="LDAP" 
     type="LBOX.Membership.LDAPMembershipProvider" 
     LDAPRoot="LDAP://10.0.1.6:389/cn=users,dc=fileserver,dc=office,dc=example,dc=com" />
```

Is there a scheme change in this line if I want it to connect to a Windows 2008 R2 Active Directory? the hostname of the AD is winvm1 the domain is office.example.com

Comment: You will be able to "connect". But I beleive you also want to bind and search ? What is the schema in your OpenDirectory LDAP ? Are your users instances of the iNetOrgPerson objectClass or some other objectClass ?

Answer (score 0):

For Active Directory, I would try:

```
LDAPRoot="LDAP://winvm1/cn=users,dc=office,dc=lbox,dc=com"
```

I removed the IP and port and replaced it with the `winvm1` server name, plus the `dc=fileserver` from your LDAP string - do you really need that when your domain is `office.example.com` ?

Alternatively, you could use Active Directory's "server-less" binding - try this path:

```
LDAPRoot="LDAP://cn=users,dc=office,dc=lbox,dc=com"
```

Does this work?